# Class decorator with generic parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, constructor, decorator

I want to write a class decorator that takes a parameter. The trouble is that I want to enforce the type of the parameter to be related to the class itself.

```js
class Options<T> {
  accept: (instance: T)=>boolean;
}

var MyOptions: Options<MyClass>={
  accept: function (instance: MyClass)
            { return true; }
};

@deco(MyOptions)
class MyClass {
  y: string;
  constructor() {
    this.y="Hello";
  }
}
```

Another goal is that I need to subclass the constructor, and give it access to the options, so the whole implementation must be written inside `deco`. This is as far as I've gotten, through trial and plenty of error:

```js
function imported<T>(instance: T, options: Options<T>): any { return {}; }

function deco<T extends {}>(options: Options<T>) {
  return function<CtorOfT extends {new(...args:any[]):T}>(ctr: CtorOfT) {
    let options_copy: Options<sub>=options;

    //replace constructor to add $accepted and $imported
    class sub extends ctr {
      $accepted: boolean;
      $imported: any;
      constructor(...args:any[]) {
        super(args);
        this.$accepted = options_copy.accept(this);
        this.$imported = imported<sub>(this, options_copy);
      }
    };
    return sub;
  }
}
```

The compiler complains about line

```js
class sub extends ctr {
```

that

```js
Base constructor return type 'T' is not a class or interface type.
```

I tried to fix that with `<T extends {}>` but it didn't quite help. It compiles when I replace

```js
new(...args:any[]):T
```

with

```js
new(...args:any[]):{}
```

which is what I'm doing, but it loses the type connection between `MyOptions` and `MyClass`. As you can easily guess, I have no idea what I'm doing (wrong).

Link to [Repl](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Options%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20accept%3A%20(instance%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20MyOptions%3A%20Options%3CMyClass%3E%3D%7B%0D%0A%20%20accept%3A%20function%20(instance%3A%20MyClass)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20return%20true%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20FooOptions%3A%20Options%3CFoo%3E%3D%7B%0D%0A%20%20accept%3A%20function%20(instance%3A%20Foo)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20return%20true%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%40deco(MyOptions)%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20y%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.y%3D%22Hello%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testIsFunction(f%3A%20Function)%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20imported%3CT%3E(instance%3A%20T%2C%20options%3A%20Options%3CT%3E)%3A%20any%20%7B%20return%20%7B%7D%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20deco%3CT%20extends%20%7B%7D%3E(options%3A%20Options%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%3CCtorOfT%20extends%20%7Bnew(...args%3Aany%5B%5D)%3AT%7D%3E(ctr%3A%20CtorOfT)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20options_copy%3A%20Options%3Csub%3E%3Doptions%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testIsFunction(ctr)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Freplace%20constructor%20to%20add%20%24accepted%20and%20%24imported%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20sub%20extends%20ctr%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24accepted%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24imported%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(...args%3Aany%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24accepted%20%3D%20options_copy.accept(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24imported%20%3D%20imported(this%2C%20options_copy)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20sub%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) tested with TSC 2.8.1  ([previous version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Options%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20accept%3A%20%3CT%3E(instance%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20MyOptions%3A%20Options%3CMyClass%3E%3D%7B%0D%0A%20%20accept%3A%20function%20%3CMyClass%3E(instance%3A%20MyClass)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20return%20true%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%40deco(MyOptions)%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20y%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.y%3D%22Hello%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testIsFunction(f%3A%20Function)%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20imported%3CT%3E(instance%3A%20T%2C%20options%3A%20Options%3CT%3E)%3A%20any%20%7B%20return%20%7B%7D%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20deco%3CT%20extends%20%7B%7D%3E(options%3A%20Options%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%3CCtorOfT%20extends%20%7Bnew(...args%3Aany%5B%5D)%3AT%7D%3E(ctr%3A%20CtorOfT)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20options_copy%3A%20Options%3Csub%3E%3Doptions%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testIsFunction(ctr)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Freplace%20constructor%20to%20add%20%24accepted%20and%20%24imported%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20sub%20extends%20ctr%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24accepted%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24imported%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(...args%3Aany%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24accepted%20%3D%20options_copy.accept(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24imported%20%3D%20imported(this%2C%20options_copy)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20sub%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A))

**Edit**: By type connection, I mean that the following should be an error:

```js
class Foo {
  x: number;
}

var FooOptions: Options<Foo>={
  accept: function (instance: Foo)
            { return true; }
};

@deco(FooOptions) //error, Foo vs MyClass
class MyClass {
  ...
```

Thanks to jcalz, I've noticed I had Options.accept declared as a generic when I shouldn't have. Edited that out, but now it complains about

```js
let options_copy: Options<sub>=options;
```

as well. I'll try to understand the discussion of [Github #16390 issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16390) but it's really convoluted.

Comment: When you say it "loses the type connection between `MyOptions` and `MyClass`" could you add code to your question that shows what you mean and what you expect to happen?  You can likely assert your way out of compiler errors, but I'm not sure what type you want the decorator to return without that code.  Seems like [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16390) may be relevant but I'm not sure.

Comment: It could be related but doesn't help. Two examples do not compile, and I can't split the definition like Zamb3zi because I can't enforce T's superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there's no way right now to have a mixin that extends a constructor of a generic type, as alluded to in [Microsoft/Typescript#16390](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16390).  If you think this is important, you might want to comment on that issue or give it a  or something.

As I mentioned in my comment, you can assert your way out of this problem... you lose some type safety inside the implementation of `deco()`, but at least from the outside (the caller's perspective) things should work.  Here's one way to do it:

```
// name for "Constructor of"
interface Ctor<T> {
  new(...args: any[]): T
}

function deco<T>(options: Options<T>) {
  // give a name to the extended T we will return
  type XT = T & {
    $accepted: boolean;
    $imported: any;
  }
  // Use Ctor<T> below
  return function <CtorOfT extends Ctor<T>>(ctr: CtorOfT) {

    // leave options_copy as Options<T>
    let options_copy: Options<T> = options;

    // first assertion: ctr as Ctor<any>
    const sub = class extends (ctr as Ctor<any>) {
      $accepted: boolean;
      $imported: any;
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(args);
        // second assestion: this as XT
        const that = this as any as XT;

        // use that instead of this
        this.$accepted = options_copy.accept(that);
        this.$imported = imported(that, options_copy);
      }

    // final assertion: sub as Ctor<XT>
    } as Ctor<XT>;
    return sub;
  }
}
```

In the above, `deco()` takes an `Options<T>` and returns a function that takes a `Ctor<T>` and returns a `Ctor<XT>`, where `XT` is the intersection of `T` and the extended properties you add to `sub`.  So you get the desired type safety guarantees when you call `deco()`.

Okay, that's the closest I could get to what you want.  Hope it helps; good luck.

Comment: Thanks! It compiles, works, does what I wanted, and I was even able to adapt it to the real code, so it's a success!